# HardDeadlineExceededError on Java Google App Engine Backend

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Do Google App Engine backends always end with a HardDeadLineExceeded after about a day of processing?

After my backend (B8) process runs for about a day and a half, it is invariably shutdown with a HardDeadLineExceeded exception.  On the dev server, it takes about two days to finish the same queued task.  I thought backends could possibly run indefinitely, though not guaranteed, according to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#ShutdownGoogle .  But, what I'm seeing is almost assuredly that the backend will be terminated within a day or so, which seems like more of a policy than happenstance due to: 
-"The machine running the backend is restarted, forcing your backend to move to a different machine."
or
-"App Engine needs to move your backend to a different machine to improve load distribution."

My task is to parse through huge XML files with Stax, and write out a set of CSV files from the results, to the blobstore.

Now that the premier feature of "Always On" is gone, it seems there is no other option than to handle the shutdown request, but this would involve saving the StAX XML Parser cursor state (which may not be possible) and writing out the outputted file frequently back to the blobstore.  So ... backends aren't really good at being backends, imo.